# Convert Epoch timestamp to date format

Tags: datetime, time, epoch

I have a `.json` file with lots of documents, each document is like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"54ff56116d"},"caption":{"created_time":"1421434541",....}
```

I need to convert `created_time` to date format in each of my documents.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 10-digit numbers as the created time, you're probably using 'Unix timestamps', which count seconds since The Epoch, which is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00 (midnight on the morning of 1st January 1970 in the UTC or GMT time zone).  If you had 13-digit numbers, it would probably be milliseconds since The Epoch, used in Java.  There are other systems, but this is a plausible guess.

There are lots of systems of functions that will convert such values into dates.  I have a C program using standard library functions that I used to validate your date:

```
$ timestamp 1421434541
1421434541 = Fri Jan 16 10:55:41 2015
$ timestamp -u 1421434541
1421434541 = Fri Jan 16 18:55:41 2015
$ timestamp -T '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -u 1421434541
1421434541 = 2015-01-16 18:55:41
$
```

<sup>(Local time zone: US/Pacific, aka America/Los_Angeles.)</sup>

The program uses `strtol()` to convert the number in a string to an `long` and then uses `localtime()` or `gmtime()` to break that into a `struct tm`, and then uses `strftime()` to format the result.

The GNU `date` command can be used to do that stuff too:

```
$ /usr/gnu/bin/date -d @1421434541 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
2015-01-16 10:55:41
$
```

Since you've not identified your host language, it is not really possible to tell you what to use.  It is pretty much guaranteed that whatever language you choose, there'll be code available to handle the conversion, though.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any specific host language, but my OS is Linux.
My main question is that how to do it for 100000 lines? I can not do it one by one,

Comment: How can you avoid doing it one by one? You've got to read the 100,000 lines (or one line with 100,000 entries) and process each one as you find it, or after you've found it, with your JSON library. You've not specified anything about the languages you're using, so it is difficult to help you much. GNU `date` deals with one date/time at a time. My `timestamp` can take as many strings as you pass to it — your O/S will probably stop it processing them all at once but you could do many thousands in a single invocation. You'll need more information than just the times...but you've not said what.